# Secure PHPMyAdmin on Ubuntu Nginx - direct access to index.php still exists

Tags: security, nginx, phpmyadmin

On an Ubuntu - Nginx webserver I try to secure PHPMyAdmin.

There are a lot of tutorials around, they propagate the use of auth_basic or allow own / deny all other IP addresses and/or use obfuscation by renaming the symlink to PHPmyadmin.
This is all fine and well, but if I use these methods, when somebody goes to domainname.tld/phpmyadmin/index.php , the loginscreen of PHPmyadmin still appears.

What could I do to get PHPmyadmin secure?

The nginx sites-available conf file contains this:

```
set $allowed 0;
if ($remote_addr = my.ip.address) {
    set $allowed 1;
}
location /phpmyadmin {
    if ($allowed != 1) {
        rewrite ^ /404 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems somewhat convoluted. Why would a regular [access directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) not be sufficient?

Comment: Yes that could be done, but there are some more locations not allowed. The main question is, how to also block  domainname.tld/phpmyadmin/index.php

Comment: With a location block just like you wrote it. You might have to keep the order in which the directives appear in mind though and it might matter what kind of matches you're using for the location blocks. AKA the phpmyadmin block should be sufficient. If it is not, it's likely that your php block is taking precedence. Hence you will still be vulnerable because people would be able to call any .php file. Maybe check [this digital ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)

Comment: Ok thanks, I found the answer as described below. Do you think this creates some kind of new vulnerability then, or is my understanding not right?

Comment: As I explained, yes. Because your original approach should've been sufficient. It wasn't so something is likely off with your configuration. Just try to access one of the other .php files in the phpmyadmin folder from a location that should be able to. If you can access that file and don't get a 404 you know you're still potentially vulnerable.

Comment: The problem with my original approach was, that it DID allow anyone to execute /phpmyadmin/index.php - the solution below prohibits that, but does allow other php files to be executed. I have not figured out how to stop that. Your link was a good one, I also used that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, added the location of index.php and directly handling the php within that location (otherwise the php is not parsed):

```
    set $allowed 0;
if ($remote_addr = my.ip.address) {
    set $allowed 1;
}
location /phpmyadmin {
    if ($allowed != 1) {
    rewrite ^ /404 break;
    }
}
location = /phpmyadmin/index.php {
    if ($allowed != 1) {
        rewrite ^ /404 break;
    }
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```